# Cache all of my internet browsing?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, cache, internet, browser

Is it possible to generate a cache of all of my internet browsing on Linux?

So, any time I visit a webpage, that page is automatically downloaded to my computer, and the next time I visit said page, it is loaded from the cache instead of actually downloading from the internet...

Assume I have, say, 4TB available for this, and I want to refresh the cache once every week(so, if I visit the website multiple times in one week, it uses the cached version, however, once the cache is more than a week old, it gets refreshed next time I visit the site).

This is for a satellite internet situation, where the connection gets throttled after 160GB of usage, so caching my computer should take a good bite out of that. Note, that I don't want to cache other computers on the network, so I just want a solution that affects my laptop and nothing else.

I am using ArchLinux if that helps...

Comment: take a look at, for example, `squid`: http://www.squid-cache.org ; and even though you can do the 'one week thing', consider that may be, the cached web is more than one week old, but is still the same, and, at the other hand, you can have a web cached for one day, and may be it changed already... usually, the correct approach, when is available, is simply ask is the data is dated, and in that case, ask for it; your caching proxy can do that.

Comment: Would this set up a server, or just affect my laptop and only my laptop? I thought squid was only for people running websites or WISP's. I just want to reduce my computers data usage

Comment: that depends on how you do it; if you just want that configuration for your laptop, and only for your laptop, you can install squid on your laptop, and use it through your browser, configuring a proxy server in the browser, in `localhost` at port `SOMENUMBER`, where `SOMENUMBER` is a port number you choose in your `squid` configuration. Note that I'm posting this as a comment, and not as an answer: this was intentional. If you know just a little, the whole explanation could take pages. Google for `squid on localhost` or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/gildas-lormeau/SingleFile) is a Firefox addon / Chrome extension that allows you to save your current page. with Ctrl+S. in a HTML file. This would work well, but would require a pressing something every page.

[There](https://craiget.com/javascript/automatically-save-html-of-every-page-you-visit) is also a Chrome extension that POSTs all of the pages you visit to your local webserver (if you don't have one you'll need to set one up). This would take more time to setup and is a bodged solution.